# How to make factorial faster?

Tags: performance, algorithm, clojure

I make simple factorial program in Clojure.

```
(defn fac [x y] 
     (if (= x 1) y (recur (- x 1) (* y x)))
)

(def fact [n] (fac n 1))
```

How can it be done faster? If it can be done some faster way.

Comment: Well, for starters, don't use Clojure if you need something to be fast. ;-)

Comment: Try annotating ``x`` and ``y`` as ints.

Comment: Also you may be interested in [this post](http://www.learningclojure.com/2013/02/clojure-is-fast-is-clojure-still-fast.html) about simple performance optimizations in Clojure.

Comment: One practical suggestion is to not use factorials. For example if you want the [k-permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#In_combinatorics) `n!/(n-k)!`, you can handle that in a single loop/recursion without calculating either `n!` or `(n-k)!`, and doing so is both faster and more reliable (less likely to overflow). Using the factorial function as a building block is rarely a good idea because it grows so quickly (only 13 distinct factorials before you overflow a 32-bit integer, IIRC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find many fast factorial algorithms here: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

As commented above, Clojure is not the best language for that. Consider using C, C++, ForTran.

Be careful with the data structures that you use, because factorials grow really fast.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of your own `fact` function (or any other), we can define this extremely fast version:

```
(def fact* (mapv fact (cons 1 (range 1 21))))
```

This will give the right results for arguments in the range from 1 to 20 in constant time. Beyond that range, your version doesn't give correct results either (i.e. there's an integer overflow with `(fact 21)`).

**EDIT**: Here's an improved implementation that doesn't need another `fact` implementation, does not overflow and should be much faster during definition because it doesn't compute each entry in its lookup table from scratch:

```
(def fact (persistent! (reduce (fn [v n] (conj! v (*' (v n) (inc n))))
                               (transient [1])
                               (range 1000))))
```

**EDIT 2**: For a different fast solution, i.e. without building up a lookup table, it's probably best to use a library that's already highly optimized. Google's general utility library Guava includes a factorial implementation.

Add it to your project by adding this Leiningen dependency: `[com.google.guava/guava "15.0"]`. Then you need to `(import com.google.common.math.BigIntegerMath)` and can then call it with `(BigIntegerMath/factorial n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my favorite:

```
(defn fact [n] (reduce *' (range 1 (inc n))))
```

The ' tells Clojure to use BigInteger transparently so as to avoid overflow.

Comment: Where is *' documented?

Comment: Here: [http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/*'](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/*')